# How to improve the performance of a 2d array?

Tags: c#, performance, optimization, wrapper

I was trying to use [Math.Net's dense matrix class](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/matrix.html). But, it doesn't support `int`. So, I have to create a wrapper for a jagged 2d array.

I knew that jagged arrays have [better performances](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1064915/A-Generic-Fast-implementation-of-a-dimensional-de).

```
Data Size          : 966 x 345
Naked 2d Array     : 10 milliseconds
Naked Jagged Array : 6 milliseconds
Jagged Wrapper     : 82 milliseconds
Dense Wrapper      : 88 milliseconds
2d Wrapper         : 62 milliseconds
```

According to my test results, a naked jagged array is the fastest of all. 
But, in terms of wrapper, the 2d wrapper is relatively faster.

Now, I have two questions:

1. Why is the jagged wrapper slower than 2d wrapper?
2. Is it possible to make the wrapper run as fast as the naked one?

.

**Source Code**

*Test Code*

```
Bitmap bmpImage = DataConverter2d.ReadGray("image.jpg");

int[][] intNakedJagged = DataConverter2d.ToInteger(bmpImage);
int[,] intNaked2d = JagMatrix<int>.To2d(intNakedJagged);

JagMatrix<int> intJaggedWrapper = new JagMatrix<int>(intNakedJagged);
DenMatrix<int> intDenWrapper = new DenMatrix<int>(intNaked2d);
Matrix<int> int2dWrapper = new Matrix<int>(intNaked2d);

Stopwatch sw1 = new Stopwatch();
sw1.Start();
double[,] dImage = DataConverter2d.ToDouble(intNaked2d);
sw1.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Naked 2d Array : " + sw1.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + " milliseconds", "Elapsed time");


Stopwatch sw2 = new Stopwatch();
sw2.Start();
double[][] dImageJagged = DataConverter2d.ToDouble(intNakedJagged);
sw2.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Naked Jagged Array : " + sw2.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + " milliseconds", "Elapsed time");


Stopwatch sw3 = new Stopwatch();
sw3.Start();
JagMatrix<double> dJagArray2d = DataConverter2d.ToDouble(intJaggedWrapper);
sw3.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Jagged Wrapper : " + sw3.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + " milliseconds", "Elapsed time");

Stopwatch sw4 = new Stopwatch();
sw4.Start();
DenMatrix<double> dDenArray2d = DataConverter2d.ToDouble(intDenWrapper);
sw4.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Dense Wrapper : " + sw4.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + " milliseconds", "Elapsed time");

Stopwatch sw5 = new Stopwatch();
sw5.Start();
Matrix<double> dArray2d = DataConverter2d.ToDouble(int2dWrapper);
sw5.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("2d Wrapper : " + sw5.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + " milliseconds", "Elapsed time");

Console.ReadKey();
```

*2d Matrix*

```
public class Matrix<T> : IDisposable where T : struct , IComparable<T>
{
    private T[,] __array2d;
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public bool IsEmpty
    {
        get
        {
            if (__array2d == null) return true;
            else return false;
        }
    }

    public Matrix() { }
    public Matrix(T[,] data)
    {
        this.Set(data);
    }

    public Matrix(int rows, int cols)
    {
        Width = rows;
        Height = cols;
        __array2d = new T[Width, Height];
    }
    public T Get(int x, int y)
    {
        if (__array2d == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("array is empty");
        }
        if (x < Width && y < Height)
        {
            if (__array2d != null)
            {
                return __array2d[x, y];
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("array is null");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            string message = string.Empty;

            if (x >= Width) message = "x-value exceeds Width ";
            if (y >= Height) message += "y-value exceeds Height ";
            message += "in Array2d.Get(x,y).";
            throw new Exception(message);
        }
    }

    public void Set(int x, int y, T val)
    {
        if (__array2d == null)
        {
            __array2d = new T[Width, Height];
        }
        else
        {
            if (Width != __array2d.GetLength(0))
            {
                __array2d = null;
                __array2d = new T[Width, Height];
            }
        }

        if (x < Width && y < Height)
        {
            __array2d[x, y] = val;
        }
        else
        {

            throw new Exception(x + ", " + Width + "," + y + "," + Height);
        }
    }

    public T this[int x, int y]
    {
        get
        {
            return Get(x, y);
        }
        set
        {
            Set(x, y, value);
        }
    }

    public void Set(T[,] arr)
    {
        if (arr != null)
        {
            int rows = arr.GetLength(0);
            int cols = arr.GetLength(1);

            __array2d = arr;
            Width = rows;
            Height = cols;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("array is null");
        }
    }

    #region IDisposable implementation
    ~Matrix()
    {
        this.Dispose(false);
    }

    protected bool Disposed { get; private set; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.Disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                // Perform managed cleanup here.
                //IDisposable disp = (IDisposable)_2dArray;

                __array2d = null;
            }

            // Perform unmanaged cleanup here.
            Width = 0;
            Height = 0;

            this.Disposed = true;
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

*2d Jagged Matrix*

```
public class JagMatrix<T> : IDisposable where T : struct , IComparable<T>
{
    private T[][] __array2d;
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public bool IsEmpty
    {
        get
        {
            if (__array2d == null) return true;
            else return false;
        }
    }

    public JagMatrix() { }
    public JagMatrix(T[][] data)
    {
        this.Set(data);
    }

    public JagMatrix(int rows, int cols)
    {
        Width = rows;
        Height = cols;

        __array2d = new T[Width][];
        for (int i = 0; i < Width; i++)
        {
            __array2d[i] = new T[Height];
        }
    }
    public T Get(int x, int y)
    {
        if (__array2d == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("array is empty");
        }
        if (x < Width && y < Height)
        {
            if (__array2d != null)
            {
                return __array2d[x][y];
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("array is null");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            string message = string.Empty;

            if (x >= Width) message = "x-value exceeds Width ";
            if (y >= Height) message += "y-value exceeds Height ";
            message += "in Array2d.Get(x,y).";

            throw new Exception(message);
        }
    }

    public void Set(int x, int y, T val)
    {
        if (__array2d == null)
        {
            __array2d = new T[Width][];
            for (int i = 0; i < Width; i++)
            {
                __array2d[i] = new T[Height];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (Width != __array2d.GetLength(0))
            {
                __array2d = null;

                __array2d = new T[Width][];
                for (int i = 0; i < Width; i++)
                {
                    __array2d[i] = new T[Height];
                }
            }
        }

        if (x < Width && y < Height)
        {
            __array2d[x][y] = val;
        }
        else
        {

            throw new Exception(x + ", " + Width + "," + y + "," + Height);
        }
    }

    public static T[,] To2d(T[][] source)
    {
        T[,] dest = new T[source.Length, source[0].Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < source[0].Length; j++)
            {
                dest[i,j] = source[i][j];
            }
        }

        return dest;
    }

    public T this[int x, int y]
    {
        get
        {
            return Get(x, y);
        }
        set
        {
            Set(x, y, value);
        }
    }

    public void Set(T[][] arr)
    {
        if (arr != null)
        {
            int rows = arr.Length;
            int cols = arr[0].Length;

            __array2d = arr;

            Width = rows;
            Height = cols;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("array is null");
        }
    }

    #region IDisposable implementation
    ~JagMatrix()
    {
        this.Dispose(false);
    }

    protected bool Disposed { get; private set; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.Disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                // Perform managed cleanup here.
                //IDisposable disp = (IDisposable)_2dArray;

                __array2d = null;
            }

            // Perform unmanaged cleanup here.
            Width = 0;
            Height = 0;

            this.Disposed = true;
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

*2d Dense Matrix*

```
public class DenMatrix<T> : IDisposable where T : struct , IComparable<T>
{
    private T[] __array1d;
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public int Length { get { return Width * Height; } }
    public bool IsEmpty
    {
        get
        {
            if (__array1d == null) return true;
            else return false;
        }
    }

    public DenMatrix() { }
    public DenMatrix(T[,] data)
    {
        this.Set(data);
    }

    public DenMatrix(int rows, int cols)
    {
        Width = rows;
        Height = cols;

        __array1d = new T[Length];
    }

    public T Get(int x, int y)
    {
        if (__array1d == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("array is empty");
        }
        if (x < Width && y < Height)
        {
            if (__array1d != null)
            {
                return __array1d[x + y * Width];
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("array is null");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            string message = string.Empty;

            if (x >= Width) message = "x-value exceeds Width ";
            if (y >= Height) message += "y-value exceeds Height ";
            message += "in Array2d.Get(x,y).";
            throw new Exception(message);
        }
    }

    public void Set(int x, int y, T val)
    {
        int length = Length;

        if (__array1d == null)
        {
            __array1d = new T[length];
        }
        else
        {
            if (length != __array1d.Length)
            {
                __array1d = null;
                __array1d = new T[length];
            }
        }

        if (x < Width && y < Height)
        {
            __array1d[x + y * Width] = val;
        }
        else
        {

            throw new Exception(x + ", " + Width + "," + y + "," + Height);
        }
    }

    public T[] To1d(T[,] array2d)
    {
        T[] array1d = new T[Length];

        for (int x = 0; x < Height; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < Width; y++)
            {
                T val = array2d[x, y];

                int index = x * Width + y;

                array1d[index] = val;
            }
        }

        return array1d;
    }

    public T this[int x, int y]
    {
        get
        {
            return Get(x, y);
        }
        set
        {
            Set(x, y, value);
        }
    }

    public void Set(T[,] arr)
    {
        if (arr != null)
        {
            int rows = arr.GetLength(0);
            int cols = arr.GetLength(1);

            Width = cols;
            Height = rows;

            __array1d = To1d(arr);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("array is null");
        }
    }

    #region IDisposable implementation
    ~DenMatrix()
    {
        this.Dispose(false);
    }

    protected bool Disposed { get; private set; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.Disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                // Perform managed cleanup here.
                //IDisposable disp = (IDisposable)_2dArray;

                __array1d = null;
            }

            // Perform unmanaged cleanup here.
            Width = 0;
            Height = 0;

            this.Disposed = true;
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

### double[][] ToDouble(int[][] image)

```
    public static double[][] ToDouble(int[][] image)
    {
        int Width = image.Length;
        int Height = image[0].Length;

        double[][] array2d = new double[Width][];

        for (int x = 0; x < Width; x++)
        {
            array2d[x] = new double[Height];

            for (int y = 0; y < Height; y++)
            {
                double d = image[x][y] / 255.0;

                array2d[x][y] = d;
            }
        }

        return array2d;
    }
```

### DataConverter2d.Todouble(Matrix image)

```
    public static Matrix<double> ToDouble(Matrix<int> image)
    {
        int Width = image.Width;
        int Height = image.Height;

        Matrix<double> array2d = new Matrix<double>(Width, Height);

        for (int x = 0; x < Width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < Height; y++)
            {
                double d = image[x, y] / 255.0;

                array2d[x, y] = d;
            }
        }

        return array2d;
    }
```

Comment: You haven't said (1) what operations are you getting poor performance on, (2) how you measured it (3) what acceptable performance is, (4) what the results of your research so far have been.  If I told you that my car was too slow, and told you nothing at all about what aspect was too slow, how I measured the speed, what my acceptable speed was, or what I'd tried so far, I imagine that you would not be able to give me good advice without knowing those things. We're in the same boat. Help us help you.

Comment: First thing to do is remove all the IDisposable code, it's useless as is. Also you should use BenchmarkDotNet instead of stopwatch, super easy to use and prevents questions about how the benchmark is made, and then, where's the code for DataConverter2d.ToDouble?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Why is the jagged wrapper slower than 2d wrapper?

I cannot recreate your test results using [this](https://gist.github.com/JoachimCoenen/6b972be0356c8c3ed32daa1ec51e3fcf) code:

```
Data Size          : 4000 x 4000
Naked 2d Array     : 188 milliseconds
Naked Jagged Array : 202 milliseconds
Jagged Wrapper     : 311 milliseconds
Dense Wrapper      : 501 milliseconds
2d Wrapper         : 343 milliseconds
```

> 2. Is it possible to make the wrapper run as fast as the naked one?

Lets try:

- simplifying the `Get(x, y)` and `Set(x, y, value)` methods and letting the arrays themselves check the boundaries:

  ```
  public T this[int x, int y]
  {
      get
      {
          try {
              return _array[x, y]; 
          } catch (IndexOutOfRangeException e) {
              throw new Exception(String.Format(
                  "index ({0}, {1}) exceeds size of Matrix ({2}, {3})",
                  x, y, Width, Height
              ));
          }
      }
      set
      {
          try {
              _array[x, y] = value; 
          } catch (IndexOutOfRangeException e) {
              throw new Exception(String.Format(
                  "index ({0}, {1}) exceeds size of Matrix ({2}, {3})",
                  x, y, Width, Height
              ));
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  Results:

  ```
  Data Size          : 4000 x 4000
  Naked 2d Array     : 186 milliseconds
  matrix (2d Wrapper): 308 milliseconds
  FastMatrix         : 246 milliseconds
  ```
- Using a [map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)) method (called `Select` in Linq):

  ```
  public FastMatrix<R> Map<R>(Func<T, R> func) where R : struct, IComparable<R>
  {
      FastMatrix<R> array2d = new FastMatrix<R>(Width, Height);

      for (int x = 0; x < Width; x++)
      {
          for (int y = 0; y < Height; y++)
          {
              array2d._array[x, y] = func(_array[x, y]);
          }
      }
      return array2d;
  }
  ```

  calling `map`:

  ```
  FastMatrix<double> dFastMatrix2 = intFastMatrix.Map(v => (double)v / 255.0);
  ```

  Results are:

  ```
  Data Size          : 4000 x 4000
  Naked 2d Array     : 186 milliseconds
  matrix (2d Wrapper): 308 milliseconds
  FastMatrix.Map     : 184 milliseconds
  ```

  That's as fast as the naked 2d Array!

Summary:

```
Data Size          : 4000 x 4000
Naked 2d Array     : 186 milliseconds
Naked Jagged Array : 200 milliseconds
Jagged Wrapper     : 308 milliseconds
Dense Wrapper      : 486 milliseconds
2d Wrapper         : 308 milliseconds
Fast versions:
FastMatrix         : 246 milliseconds
FastMatrix.Map     : 184 milliseconds
```

Full code is [here](https://gist.github.com/JoachimCoenen/6b972be0356c8c3ed32daa1ec51e3fcf).

Comment: @anonymous: sorry, I accidentally pressed the 'Save' button too early. `which code?` I just filled the arrays with random data (see updated answer)

Answer (score 2):

> According to my test results, a naked jagged array is the fastest of all. But, in terms of wrapper, the 2d wrapper is relatively faster.

Well, my tests (running the code from [J. Coenen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52636263/how-to-improve-the-performance-of-a-2d-array/52762184#52762184) via exe built in release mode) show different results:

```
Data Size          : 4000 x 4000
Naked 2d Array     : 70 milliseconds
Naked Jagged Array : 67 milliseconds
Jagged Wrapper     : 205 milliseconds
Dense Wrapper      : 391 milliseconds
2d Wrapper         : 227 milliseconds
Faster versions:
FastMatrix         : 143 milliseconds
FastMatrix.Map     : 130 milliseconds
```

I've ran it serveral times and both Jagged implementations are little faster than their 2d counterparts. The Dense implementation is significantly slower.

> Is it possible to make the wrapper run as fast as the naked one?

Absolutely! Your `Get` / `Set` methods are doing a lot of unnecessary work, basically duplicating the CLR work in an inefficient, redundant and not fully correct way (for instance there is no check for negative indices). Don't do that. *J. Coenen* showed the right direction, but you can go further. C# 7.0 introduced a (long awaited by people who care about performance) feature called [Ref locals and returns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#ref-locals-and-returns) which allows you to create custom class indexers with the similar performance characteristics to the CLR arrays. It's even accompanied with use case/example for matrices :)

All you need is to change your class indexers to:

**Matrix<T>**

```
public ref T this[int x, int y] => ref __array2d[x, y];
```

**JagMatrix<T>**

```
public ref T this[int x, int y] => ref __array2d[x][y];
```

**DenMatrix<T>**

```
public ref T this[int x, int y] => ref __array1d[x + y * Width];
```

Now the same test shows different results:

```
Data Size          : 4000 x 4000
Naked 2d Array     : 71 milliseconds
Naked Jagged Array : 68 milliseconds
Jagged Wrapper     : 77 milliseconds
Dense Wrapper      : 355 milliseconds
2d Wrapper         : 79 milliseconds
Faster versions:
FastMatrix         : 144 milliseconds
FastMatrix.Map     : 132 milliseconds
```

As you can see, the Jagged / 2d wrappers have almost the same performance as their "naked" counterparts. The Dense implementation is still significantly slower (probably due to manual calculation of the index in addition to CRL bounds checks), and "faster versions" from the other answer are at the middle.

Comment: @anonymous There is a difference between .net 2.0 and c# 2.0 (c#7.0 perfectly works with .net 2.0). Also it's not correct to modify the question and put additional requirements after it has received answers - otherwise you are just wasting our time. I don't care about virtual points, but I do care about my time which can be spent for something more useful. So, why added c# 2.0 tag? Is it still valid? Or you meant .net 2.0?